# Programmatically check in runtime whether variable is const in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reflection, runtime, metaprogramming

Is it possible to know programmatically in runtime whether variable is const in JS?

For example:

```
const a = {};
const b = 5;

var c = {};
var d = 6;

var e = a;
var f = b;
var g = c;
var h = d;

isConst(a); // true
isConst(b); // true
isConst(c); // false
isConst(d); // false
isConst(e); // false
isConst(f); // false
isConst(g); // false
isConst(h); // false
```

I don't even know how to approach this issue, assuming I don't want to use external tools (from outside the JS runtime environment), or something like eval().

Maybe it's possible somehow with JavaScript's `Proxy()` or `Reflect()`?

If there's no solution that determine if const or not without making changes in the checked code/module/function/block itself, I can maybe accept solutions that require some decorative/wrapping modifications to the code/function.

Maybe something that parse the `Function()` prototype field that contains the stringified text of the function body?

Maybe we can leverage exceptions here? For example, to catch the exception that raised when you try to manipulate a constant variable, and use it to understand the situation?

Comment: Why do you need it? This looks like an XY problem. What's the use-case for this? I would try the approach with `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you hand over a primitive value - to a function or another variable - you get this value and not the variable and it's kind of declaration.

To get the wanted, Javascript needs an implementation of each type to check the mutability.